# Multiple Levels of Sorting without module

Tags: python, sorting

[This article](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) states that you can use multiple levels of sorting with the `operator` module.

> The operator module functions allow multiple levels of sorting. For example, to sort by grade then by age:

```
>>>sorted(student_objects, key=attrgetter('grade', 'age'))
[('john', 'A', 15), ('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12)]
```

This should be possible to do the standard way without needing a module:

```
sorted(student_objects, key=lambda student: student.age #somehow add another
```

I can't figure out the standard way to do this though, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Do what the function in `operator` does and return a tuple:

```
key=lambda student: (student.grade, student.age)
```